# How to set default value to the parameter of stored procedure in Stimulsoft report?

Tags: stimulsoft

I use stored procedure that call table base function for get data in my report.This procedure has a parameter that when I try to get preview get me error . I want set default value for this parameter to get preview with out run app.

Is this possible?

How to do this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default value in Expression.